# why Getting Acces Denied while uploading file using aws-sdk-php?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm somehow lost here, I'm new in aws so I've installed aws-sdk-php in myproject, and I'm trying to test the upload; here is the piece of code of the script:

```
require '.vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

// Instantiate an S3 client
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'key'    => 'key ... ',
        'secret' => 'secret key ... ',
    )
)); 
$file_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
try {
    $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => 'bucket_name',
        'Key'    => $_FILES['file']['name'],
        'Body'   => fopen($file_name, 'r'),
        'ACL'    => 'public-read',
    ));
    echo " upload succed !!";
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file.\n";
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

this code is working fine from a local test, but when trying to do test the same script in a project in a folder in s3 ; I get this error :

```
There was an error uploading the file. Access Denied
```

any idea plz ?
thanks.

Comment: Have you checked your permissions?

Comment: thanks , How do i check it ? cause it's not who control the access rights ! i would to understand from where can be the error ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a restriction of public ip.
However , the script is clean and right.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try create instance how:

```
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
        'key' => 'key',
        'secret' => 'secret',
        'region' => 'eu-west-1'
    ));
```

use your region

Comment: try set in factory array without 'credentials', look in my example